# Cannot import ecdsa library in python

Tags: python, pip, ecdsa

I am trying to import ecdsa library in python but it is giving me this error:

```
Unable to import 'ecdsa'pylint(import-error)
```

I have tried this command to install ecdsa library: `pip install ecdsa`
But still it is not working

[image]

Comment: That is not a Python error, it seems to be a `pylint` error. When you run the program, do you get the Python message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecdsa'` with a traceback that reports the line of code and its line number? If not, then just ignore the `pylint` error.

Comment: @BoarGules Yes, I do get this error when  I run the program ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecdsa'. What should I do?

Comment: In between the warnings from `pip` I see "condition already satisfied". That says that `pip` thinks you have `ecdsa` installed already. So it is something to do either with `pip` or your execution environment. Try importing the module from an IDLE session or from a Python console session and see if that import works. Also, please *edit* your question (link bottom left next to Share) and paste the full response you get from `pip` into your question, formatted as code using the `{}` button. You are likelier to get more and better help that way. Posting screen images is contrary to SO guidelines.

Comment: if you get `ModuleNotFoundError` then you may have the most common problem - you have two Python installed and you install module in one `Python` but you run code in other  Python. You should compare versions `pip -V` and `python -V` or use `python -m pip install ...`